# Laravel 5.2 Storing an array of values in session

Tags: arrays, ajax, session, laravel-5

I am trying to store values of file paths during the Ajax upload. This is my code:

```
public function ajaxUpload() {
  $name = "";
  $path = public_path('files/uploads/articles/');

  if (Input::hasFile('file')) {
    $files = Input::file('file');
    $filePath = [];

  foreach($files as $file){
      $fP = $path.$file->getClientOriginalName();
      return json_encode($fP);
      Image::make($file)->resize(100, 100)->save($path.'/'.$file->getClientOriginalName());
  }

  if (Session::has('file.Path')){
    Session::push('file.Path', $fP);
    Session::save();
  }
  else {
    Session::put('file.Path', $fP);

    Session::save();
  }

  return json_encode(Session::get('file.Path'));
}
```

The output of $fp in the console is:

```
"\/home\/vagrant\/Projects\/myProject\/public\/files\/uploads\/articles\/image_2733536a64.png"
```

And the error is:

```
 LOG.error: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in /home/vagrant/Projects/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php:411
```

And when I try like this:

```
public function ajaxUpload() {
  $name = "";
  $path = public_path('files/uploads/articles/');

  if (Input::hasFile('file')) {
    $files = Input::file('file');

  foreach($files as $file){
      $filePath[] = $path.'/'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
      Image::make($file)->resize(100, 100)->save($path.'/'.$file->getClientOriginalName());
    }
      Session::put('filePath', $filePath);
      return json_encode($filePath);
   }
   return 'string';
}
```

Then it stores each of the paths separately and not in one array, so I only save one path in DB.

Comment: can you try without `Session::save()` method

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: can you tell what's the output of your `$fp` variable?

Comment: I have edit the question with the $fp output

Comment: Why your file path `$fP = $path.$file->getClientOriginalName();` is different than ` $filePath[] = $path.'/'.$file->getClientOriginalName();` ?  One got `/` and other don't

Comment: That was a typo, but it changes nothing unfortunately

Comment: Got it! you are returning in loop before Session is called.. comment `return json_encode($fP);` and try it

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110523/discussion-between-muhammad-kashif-abbasi-and-marco).

Comment: No worries, I am changing the approach completely, I will send file paths to hidden fields in the form and not be dependent on session.